# SimpleMessageListenerContainer AbstractMethodError in Spring Integration DSL with RabbitMQ

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-integration

I have following RabbitMQ Configuration

```
@Configuration
@IntegrationComponentScan
public class RabbitConfig {

@Autowired // TODO constructor!
private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

public RabbitConfig(
        @Value("${article.inbound.queue}") String queueName,
        @Value("${article.inbound.exchange}") String exchangeName,
        @Value("${article.inbound.routingkey}") String routingKey) {
    this.queueName = queueName;
    this.exchangeName = exchangeName;
    this.routingKey = routingKey;
}

@Bean
Exchange exchange() {
    return ExchangeBuilder
            .topicExchange(this.exchangeName)
            .durable(true)
            .build();
}

@Bean
Queue queue() {
    return QueueBuilder.durable(queueName).build();
}

@Bean
Binding binding() {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(queue())
            .to(exchange())
            .with(routingKey)
            .noargs();
}

@Bean
public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter() {
    return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
}

@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer articleListenerContainer(
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory);
    container.setQueues(queue());
    container.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
    return container;
}
```

}

And simple Spring Integration Flow

```
@Bean
IntegrationFlow fromMessageBroker(SimpleMessageListenerContainer messageListener) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(Amqp.inboundAdapter(messageListener))
            .log()
            .handle(message -> {
                final MessageHeaders headers = message.getHeaders();
                final Object assetId = headers.get("assetId");
                log.info(assetId);
            })
            .get();
}
```

When I start Spring Boot everything is fine until I publish message to exchange which my defined queue is bind. Then all processing goes further and after that SimpleMessageListenerContainer crashes.

```
2018-09-20 13:11:08.240  INFO 49400 --- [           main] c.p.ftppush.article.MessageConsumer      : Started MessageConsumer in 1.743 seconds (JVM running for 2.386)
2018-09-20 13:11:12.309  INFO 49400 --- [erContainer#0-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : GenericMessage [payload=byte[0], headers={amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=NON_PERSISTENT, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=article.original.orgn.123, replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@1b7db656, amqp_receivedExchange=que.article.content.pf.normal.trigger, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@1b7db656, amqp_deliveryTag=1, assetId=1qh22m9027k6d1jz29tsi510x5, amqp_consumerQueue=exc.article.content, amqp_redelivered=false, id=0d04f22a-991f-000b-63f5-5cb087b915ab, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-bK2-KaIxWpk57HJeQ_38AQ, timestamp=1537441872308}]
2018-09-20 13:11:12.310  INFO 49400 --- [erContainer#0-1] com.perform.ftppush.article.Flow         : 1qh22m9027k6d1jz29tsi510x5
2018-09-20 13:11:12.317 ERROR 49400 --- [erContainer#0-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer thread error, thread abort.

java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.integration.channel.interceptor.WireTap.postSend(Lorg/springframework/messaging/Message;Lorg/springframework/messaging/MessageChannel;Z)V
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel$ChannelInterceptorList.postSend(AbstractMessageChannel.java:607) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:460) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:227) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:45) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:97) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:497) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceiveMessage(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:465) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundGateway.access$1000(AmqpInboundGateway.java:66) ~[spring-integration-amqp-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundGateway$Listener.process(AmqpInboundGateway.java:315) ~[spring-integration-amqp-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundGateway$Listener.onMessage(AmqpInboundGateway.java:263) ~[spring-integration-amqp-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1414) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1337) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1324) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1303) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:817) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:801) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$700(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:77) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1042) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) [na:na]

2018-09-20 13:11:12.322 ERROR 49400 --- [erContainer#0-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Stopping container from aborted consumer
2018-09-20 13:11:12.322  INFO 49400 --- [erContainer#0-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Waiting for workers to finish.
2018-09-20 13:11:12.322  INFO 49400 --- [erContainer#0-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Successfully waited for workers to finish.
```

As you can see in logs flow goes to the end and then this container crashes. Unfortunately there is no useful information in exception trace. I'm wondering why it is like that. I was trying to redirect this messages in this flow into MessageChannel and then handle them but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check whether you have libraries in the same versions e.g in stacktrace you may spot that spring-messaging is in different version than spring-integration.
Maybe that is the issue?

If you could post your pom.xml or other build config we may  investigate more if needed.

Here you may find some explanation of this kind of error
https://www.pixelstech.net/article/1469241003-Java-AbstractMethodError-explained-and-demonstrated

Comment: Thanks incompatible versions of spring-integration-core and spring-messaging was an issue. I was using 
spring-boot-starter-integration which provided 5.0.6.RELEASE while I was providing 5.0.5.RELEASE for spring-integration-amqp.

After upgrading into 5.0.8.RELEASE it works properly without error. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I helped with this issue :)